# How to change default subnet for Internet Connection Sharing on Windows

Tags: networking, windows-10, ip, ethernet, internet-sharing

By default, when sharing an Internet connection with other network user's, their IP will belong to the `192.168.137.1/24` subnet.

To change this default value, one can change the registry: in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters`

I changed the `ScopeAddress` and `ScopeAddressBackup` key to `192.168.1.1`, and added a new entry `StandaloneDHCPAddress`, which I also set to `192.168.1.1`. After restarting my PC, and checking in cmd, Internet access is still being shared on the default subnet.

Is there any step that I'm missing to enable this change?

I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Try to also set `ScopeAddressBackup`.

Comment: @harrymc, thank you very much. I forgot to mention I also did that with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little too late, but maybe my answer can help others in the future. I was having the same problem on Windows 11 and the only way  to change the subnet was to add a new key as fallows:

On Regidit Navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters`.

Right-click on the Parameters key and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value.

Name the new value "ScopeMask" and double-click on it to edit its value.

Set the value to 0x00FFFF00, which is equivalent to 255.0.0.0 in decimal format.

Close the Registry Editor and restart the computer.